# Inserir imagem em css dentro de tabelas em HTML

Tags: html, css

Bom dia, gostaria de inserir uma imagem dentro de uma coluna na tabela, deixando a mesma no centro.

O máximo que consegui fazer é conforme código abaixo, porém dessa forma ela fica com uma borda em volta como se fosse uma coluna a mais.

```css
.Red {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

.Yellow {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid yellow;
}

.Verde {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" border border-bottom="1" border-left="double" border-right="1" border-top="1" border-bottom-style="solid" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="300" border="0" colspan="2">Teste Amarelo</td>
    <td width="300" colspan="2">Teste Verde</td>
    <td width="300" colspan="2">Teste Vermelho</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="Yellow" width="20"></td>
    <td width="280"></td>
    <td class="Verde" width="20"></td>
    <td width="280"></td>
    <td class="Red"></td>
    <td width="280"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Seu texto não condiz com o seu exemplo. Você diz que quer inserir uma imagem na coluna, mas no código você faz a própria coluna ser imagem; fora o fato que você literalmente definiu 6 colunas e estranhou o fato de "ter criado colunas a mais". Ficou bem confuso.

Comment: Vc já tentou colocar a imagem no formato .png?

Comment: É que foi a única forma que consegui inserir a imagem dentro da coluna, como imagem eu não consegui fazer aparecer também. As várias colunas são para ficar no tamanho que eu quero, mas sei que não é a forma correta de se fazer

Comment: Cara porque vc não coloca uma tag <img> ou até uma <div> dentro da TD e alinha ela da forma que quiser. Não deu para entender direito o que vc quer...

Comment: Eu tenho um jsp que vai trazer o nome do status (Red, Green, Yellow) preciso que dentro da coluna no lugar dessa variável apareça o sinal referente ao farol. Com divs dentro da TD eu não tentei mas com a tag img eu não consigo fazer a referência com a variável (pelo menos não sei como fazer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se era exatamente isso que vc queria, mas veja que vc pode usar `text-align: center` e `vertical-align: middle` para centralizar elementos dentro da `td` e não precisa estilizar diretamente a `td`, pois se vc assim vc vai ficar "preso" no layout da própria célula, então o indicado é que se use um elemento dentro da `td`.

```css
.Red {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
}

.Yellow {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid yellow;
}

.Verde {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
img {
    display: block;
}
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: calc(100% / 6);
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="300" colspan="2">Teste Amarelo</td>
        <td width="300" colspan="2">Teste Verde</td>
        <td width="300" colspan="2">Teste Vermelho</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="Red"></div></td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td><img src="https://placecage.com/100/100"></td>
        <td>345</td>
        <td><div class="Verde"></div></td>
        <td>789</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Usar a div dentro do td resolveu o problema. Muito obrigado pela ajuda e pelas dicas.

Comment: @GuilhermeMontagnani que bom que deu certo! Se a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma considere marca-la como Aceita, nesse ícone `✔` abaixo das setinhas no lado esquerdo da minha resposta :) assim o site não fica com perguntas abertas pendentes sem resposta aceita. Depois se aparecer outra resposta que vc julgue mais adequada vc pode trocar a marcação de aceita para ela se vc achar que foi melhor para vc.